# C# Load TGA and manipulate TGA image

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, alpha-transparency, tga

I've been searching for an answer but cant get my head around this. I use C# alot but never actually dealt with graphics. I want to load a TGA image (32 bit) and then manipulate the color data ( including alpha channel ). How would a dumb dumb begin to approach this problem.

The basic manipulation I want to do is to change the coloring:
The input is a mask image with 4 fixed colors (black, red, green, blue and alpha channel). I want to pull each channel and create a new image with certain colors instead of the original ones.

For example. Say I have a mask image with Black and Green and Alpha data.
I want to make a new image with color1 where its black ( no channel is used ), color2 where its Green ( Only full green is used ) and color3 where its Alpha ( Only where alpha is used )

The input images don't have overlapping channels or alpha (A pixel has only one type of data, red, green, blue or alpha)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having issues loading in a TGA file then reading the binary data within?  Or the actual manipulations are the problem?  A little code to show where you are will help others to help you further.

Comment: I am looking for knowledge. I haven't began coding because I don't have a starting point for this.